# when committing in visual studio team explorer it shows different account not mine

Tags: git, visual-studio-2017, team-explorer

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PSkph.jpg)

I'm working on a project on visual studio and created a git on VSTS on my account as git but when I try to commit any updates on visual studio it uses different account than mine even though in account settings it shows only my account, how to remove this account and make visual studio commit with my account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Sourcetree for git commit,fetch with your account details or follow procedure in https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2013/02/26/customize-git-settings-in-visual-studio/

Comment: Thanks a lot! it worked for me, it was driving me nuts, I appreciate it a lot